# How can I Convert BlockFrost API Code to Dandelion API?

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, api, blockfrost, independent-service-providers

I have somehow managed to get a lot of code for BlockFrost API, however, I want to build some free applications for people to monitor blockchain data from a website dashboard.

To take advantage of the better fee structure I want to convert the code to the Dandelion API, The original code is just a series of function calls calling different endpoints and returning different results. Is there a way to programmatically convert the old APIs into Dandelion compatible APIs?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to change to/from. Sounds to me like you need to do a swap out of API/URL calls (easy enough to do manually, or search/replace) but you will also need to handle any potential difference in data structure that you get back from the new APIs. Or I might be misunderstanding this request.

Comment: Thanks it's sorted. Dandelion makes a bunch of different APIs the rest ones are to convert to blockfrost and vice versa, but there's a few small tricks to converting the rest. I basically made some factory function around the blockfrost API sdk

Comment: Ok great. It might be helpful to create your own answer and accept it as the best answer, in order help anyone else that has a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Dandelion is now running an Blockfrost endpoint too.